# Substring of a Substring

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a text field (field named "BiographyText" in the "Employs" table) in SQL Server 2008 which stores KPI target figures:

```
rebfirst60,
reifirst1.3,
retfirst50
```

The first target is 60, for RebFirst, the second is 1.3 for ReiFirst and 50 for the third, RetFirst.

I want to be able to return the 3 different numerical values, as these would be deemed the targets for each kpi for a certain employee.

I am having a complete mind block trying to figure out the best way to do this, any advice/help?

Overall I am trying to find the kpiname ("rebfirst") and then retrieve the next 2 characters/digits

I tried the following, but it errors on function 2 of the first substring, as it is non-numeric:

```
select SUBSTRING(biographytext,SUBSTRING('rebfirst',1,2),2) from employs
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not store as separate values and rows? Normalisation of a database exists to avoid this type of problem

Comment: Or was it simply formatting that makes it look like one value?

Comment: The employs table has one row for each employee and now where to store such targets as such, so as a workaround this text field is being used

Comment: @Stuart1044: why not create a new table?

Comment: Firstly, I would suggest a database refactor to normalize your data structure better, so that each of these 3 values were in their own columns (ideally in another table with a key that references back to this one). (suggestion only, more understanding of your current data model would be required for a more definitive recommendation)

Comment: as @gbn says, storing two logical attributes in one column is wrong. I prefer joins to string manipulation. Additionaly, the value will be typed so you would't need to convert/parse.

Comment: We are a bit stuck as the software UI would only update this core table (employs), so if new targets are updated via the UI they would be in the format above

Comment: I don't need the actual kpiname from this just the value

Comment: is the kpinname value of fixed length?

Comment: Perhaps you could use any number of string splitting functions first. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this now by using the following:

```
select 
SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(biographytext,1,10),9,2) as RebookingFirst,
SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(biographytext,11,20),12,3) as ReInventFirst,
SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(biographytext,21,30),16,3) as ReCreateFirst,
SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(biographytext,31,40),20,2) as RetentionFirst,
SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(biographytext,41,50),23,2) as ReferralsFirst
from employs
```

This gives me the results for each kpi

Comment: in case of **Dynamic**, Again it would not Work.

Comment: @Luv how so? the entries into the field will be of set length and order

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN PatIndex('%[a-z]%',REVERSE(BiographyText)) > 0
      THEN RIGHT(BiographyText,PatIndex('%[a-z]%',REVERSE(BiographyText))-1)
      ELSE '' END AS target 
FROM employs
```

and also **[check another solution using function](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/extracting-numbers-with-sql-server)**

Comment: +1: Nice solution. I just had to try it out in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7a5c8/1)

Answer (score 0):

From Post ***The first target is 60, for RebFirst, the second is 1.3 for ReiFirst and 50 for the third, RetFirst.***

From Comment ***I don't need the actual kpiname from this just the value***

The following `Query` will give you the Answer.

```
select case column_name when 'rebfirst60' then 60
       when 'reifirst1.3' then 1.3
       when 'retfirst50' then 50
from employs
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but this would mean knowing the actual value, but they are dynamic